# Extracting archive file in linker script

Tags: c, gcc, ld, unix-ar, linker-scripts

I am trying to deal with a problem like the following one:

Assume that I have a library libxyz.a created from:

```
/* main.c */
int main(void)
{
  int a;
}
```

compiled and archived with:

```
gcc -c main.c -o abc.o && ar cr libxyz.a abc.o
```

How do I have to write linker script in order to put abc.o exactly where it is expected to be?

I was trying to handle it in such way:

```
/* script.ld */
SEARCH_DIR(.)
INPUT(-lxyz)
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { xyz:abc(.text) }
   .data : { xyz:abc(.data) }
   .bss  : { xyz:abc(.bss) }
}
```

but after running:

```
ld -T script.ld
```

I get:

```
ld: cannot find xyz:abc
```

I couldn't find any example of extracting archives in linker files on forums. The only thing I have found was the linker's documentation, which only contains information about `archive:file` construction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just had to deal with same problem today, so if someone else bumps into this question: some file extensions are missing. Something like works fine:

```
SECTIONS
{
   .text : { libxyz.a:abc.o(.text) }
   .data : { libxyz.a:abc.o(.data) }
   .bss  : { libxyz.a:abc.o(.bss) }
}
```

One also needs to deal with paths (if library is actually somewhere/libxyz.a).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is problem with your ld because I tried your script on my machine it ran correctly without error. my ld version is GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.22

Comment: Ok, I have changed LD version. It does not raise error, but `objdump -t a.out` still does not present `main` symbol